# clear cached TFS client credentials

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Please help me to clear TFS cached credentials using c# code. I'm using TFS API to access source code hosted by the Dev ops TFS server at https://dev.azure.com

sometimes (after domain password is changed) it raises 401 error when access the source code server. Please find code sample used to connect below:

```
    var u = "https://dev.azure.com/orgid";

    var vssCred = new VssClientCredentials();
    if (cacheCred)
        vssCred.Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage(); // tried with storage and without

    Logger.Debug("getting vsts collection for url:{0}", u);
    TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(u, vssCred);
    try
    {
        Logger.Debug("authenticating");

        tpc.Authenticate();
        tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
```

it uses `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient.15.131.1` and `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client.15.131.1` packages.

I've tried to clear cached credentials using the code like below:

```
IEnumerable<string> ClearCachedTokens(VssCredentials cred, Uri address)
{
    if (cred == null) return null;
    var res = new Collection<string>();
    foreach (VssCredentialsType enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(VssCredentialsType)))
        try
        {
            var token = cred.Storage.RetrieveToken(address, enumValue);
            if (token != null)
            {
                var tokenData = string.Join(";", token.Properties.Select(_ => string.Format("{0}={1}", _.Key, _.Value)));
                Logger.Debug("got token {0} {1}", enumValue, tokenData);
                cred.Storage.RemoveToken(address, token);
                res.Add(address.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ec)
        {
            Logger.Warn("can't clear token type:{0} error:{1}", enumValue, ec.Message);
        }
    return res;
}
```

but it does not return any entry and the error still persist.

However error is gone when I delete `%appdata%Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache` content and run `tf.exe get` command. It asks me for login and password and then 401 error is not shown any more when `tpc.Authenticate();` is executed.

How can I clear cached credentials in the `Cache` folder using the `TeamFoundationServer.Client` or `TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient` API?

Answer (score 0):

The credential might have been saved in the Credential Manager store (`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager`) in the *Generic Credentials* group.

Comment: I can't find in the Generic credentials nothing that looks like _tfs_ _vsts_ or _azure_. Also I'd like to remind that clearing `%appdata%Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache` folder makes `tf.exe` to ask for login and password. So I know the place where it is stored